# The setState function in react doesn't change the state of my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to switch between components when a button is clicked. The problem is that the state doesn't change. I understand that setState is asynchronous, but it should log the change when I press the button for a second time.  Here is my code:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <div> Inside ComponentOne</div>;
  }
}

class Component2 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <div>Inside ComponentTwo</div>;
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  ComponentOneState = "ComponentOneState";
  ComponentTwoState = "ComponentTwoState";
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        CurrentState: this.ComponentOneState
     };
    this.switchState = this.switchState.bind(this);
   }

  switchState(){
    console.log(this.state.CurrentState);
    if(this.state === this.ComponentOneState){
      this.setState = {
        CurrentState : this.ComponentTwoState
      }
    }
    else{
      this.setState = {
         CurrentState : this.ComponentOneState
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.CurrentState === this.ComponentOneState ){
    return <div>
       <Component1 />
       <button onClick = {this.switchState}>Submit</button>
    </div>;
    }
    else return <div>
      <Component2 />
      <button onClick = {this.switchState}>Submit</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: setState is a method : `this.setState({ CurrentState : this.ComponentTwoState })`

Comment: I made the change and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently assigning a new value to `setState`, but `setState` is a function you should call:

```
this.setState({
  CurrentState: this.ComponentTwoState
})
```

You also need to compare against `this.state.CurrentState` instead of `this.state` in `switchState` as shown in [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxq9r0xpyl).

Answer (score 0):

You're using `setState` on the wrong way. It should be used like:

```
switchState(){
    console.log(this.state.CurrentState);
    if(this.state === this.ComponentOneState){
      this.setState({ CurrentState : this.ComponentTwoState })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({ CurrentState : this.ComponentOneState })
    }
}
```

You should React the docs from [React State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), to avoid this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two corrections :

1. In `switchState` condition check should be

   ```
   if (this.state.CurrentState === this.ComponentOneState) {
   ```

instead  `if(this.state === this.ComponentOneState){`

2. `setState` is a function.Assigning object will not update state.Instead,it should be,

   ```
    this.setState ( {
       CurrentState: this.ComponentOneState
    })
   ```

   and

   ```
   this.setState ({
           CurrentState : this. ComponentTwoState
         })
   ```

Working [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/82mz17m9pj)